# Python MacOS Loop Files Get File Info

Tags: python, macos, operating-system, attributes, xattr

I am trying to loop through all mp3 files in my directory in MacOS Monterrey and for every iteration get the file's more info attributes, like Title, Duration, Authors etc. I found a post saying use xattr, but when i create a variable with xattr it doesn't show any properties or attributes of the files. This is in Python 3.9 with xattr package

```
import os
import xattr
directory = os.getcwd()
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    # checking if it is a file
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print(f)
        x = xattr.xattr(f)
        xs = x.items()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xattr is not reading mp3 metadata or tags, it is for reading metadata that is stored for the particular file to the filesystem itself, not the metadata/tags thats stored inside the file.

In order to get the data you need, you need to read the mp3 file itself with some library that supports reading *ID3* of the file, for example: eyed3.

Here's a small example:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import eyed3

root_directory = Path(".")
for filename in root_directory.rglob("*.mp3"):
    mp3data = eyed3.load(filename)
    if mp3data.tag != None:
        print(mp3data.tag.artist)
    print(mp3data.info.time_secs)
```

Comment: what is the Data = None used for?

Comment: it was leftover from before i rewrite the example..